# How to plot different files information in a different graph using a loop

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a program in octave that read a file, then some functions takes different parts of that file to make some plots. But now I want to read many files and creates a plot for each file. The program that I have, read these files, but at the moment of plotting, it creates multiple plots, but with the same data file (first data file).

I already try using hold on and hold off, but it did not work.

```
myfiles = dir('*.lvm');     % To load every file of .lvm

%%% - To read files
for i = 1:length(myfiles)            % Loop with the number of files
 files   = myfiles(i).name;       % Structure element with file's names
 n(:,:,i)= dlmread(files,'',2,1);% To read the contain

CM1N1 = n(:,2,:);
CM2N1 = n(:,3,:);
CM3N1 = n(:,4,:);
CM4N1 = n(:,5,:);

N1m(:,:,:) = [CM1N1 CM2N1 CM3N1 CM4N1];

%========================================================================%
% Calling all functions
%========================================================================%

%--- Function config_horizontale which plot X position and has the respective info
[Nmean1m]=config_horizontale(n,N1m); 

end
'''
AND THIS IS A PART OF THE FUNCTION

''' function [Nmean1m]=config_horizontale(n,N1m)

%=========================================================================%
% To plot 
%=========================================================================%

Nmean1m = mean(N1m); 

xM = 20:20:80;  

i=1;
figure 
plot(xM,Nmean1m(:,:,i),'-+')
end
```

As 'i' is the number of files, I need,first to plot the first file, then the second one and so on and on. Thanks in advance.

Here you will find an example of the file

```
LabVIEW Measurement 
-0.004110   0.003667    -0.007486   0.003185    -0.005198   -0.005292   
-0.001542   0.001109    -0.002435   0.003185    -0.005198   0.003184    
-0.006678   0.006224    -0.002435   0.000531    -0.010615   0.000358    
-0.006678   -0.001448   -0.007486   0.005839    -0.005198   -0.002467
-0.006678   0.003667    -0.004961   0.005839    -0.007906   -0.002467   
-0.006678   0.003667    -0.002435   0.008493    -0.007906   0.003184
```

Comment: Plesse create a MCVE

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the huge delay. I just edited the program to be run. I can not put my program because is quite big. But I think like this it is possible to figure it out what the problem is. Please let me know if do you need more details. Thank you very much.